# Hide excess part of image that is outside of the image in front

Tags: css

[image]

These are two images, one is the turtle and the other is that not so circle thingy in front, I want to hide the part that has not been touched by the not so circle thingy, how will I do that? These images are both `.PNG` files.

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <img src="/assets/img/tutle.jpg" class="img" style="position: absolute;" />
    <img src="/assets/img/round.png" class="img" style="position: relative;"/>
</div>
```

Additional:
 I will also make the `round.png` animate (spin).

Comment: Check this article, might be helpful https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: This is not something that should be solved with CSS. It should be solved by uploading an image edited with image editing software. Since you're using PNG, you should be able to mask out or delete the portions that you don't want to show and save with transparency, if the desired effect is to see the page around the roundish edge.

Comment: Post the URL of the images... I am not feeling like opening Photoshop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the CSS `mask` property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask

Comment: can this be applied for `CSS3`?

Comment: its not working sir, because I will make the not circle thingy animate

Comment: @GGw how about `clip-path` of animated svg?

Comment: I kinda dont understand that one sir, Im sorry